# Como poner texto estilo editor de código en mi web

Tags: html, css

Quiero implementar texto que tenga formato tipo código así como se muestra en la imagen que saqué de la página de w3schools.

Es decir, quiero escribir dentro de un div algo como lo que tienen ellos, o sea que el estilo final que se muestre al cargar el sitio en el navegador se parezca al que tiene un editor de código en lugar de texto normal

Dejaré más imágenes de ejemplos de otras Webs, lo que quiero lograr es alguno de esos modals.

[image: Imagen de w3schools]

[image: Imagen de Mozilla developer]

[image: Imagen de Desarrolloweb.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar por pantalla etiquetas sin que estas sean funcionales, necesitamos hacer uso de las cadenas:

- `&lt;` Que en pantalla saldría reflejada como <
- `&gt;` Que en pantalla saldría reflejada como >

De esta forma aplicando estas dos cadenas seremos capaces de escribir etiquetas "falsas" para que se vean por pantalla y no afecten al código.

Te dejo aquí un pequeño ejemplo (no muy bonito estéticamente) para que veas como implementarlas.

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(146, 146, 146);
}
    
#codigo{
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 7px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Prueba</h1>
    <div id="codigo">
        <pre>

 &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
 &lt;html&gt;
 &lt;head&gt;
 &lt;title&gt;Page Title&lt;/title&gt;
 &lt;/head&gt;

 &lt;h1&gt;This is a Heading&lt;/h1&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;Thisis a paragraph&lt;/p&gt;

 &lt;/body&gt;
 &lt;/html&gt;

        </pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que quiero escribir dentro de un div algo como lo que tienen ellos, o sea que el estilo se parezca al que tiene un editor de código en lugar de texto normal

Comment: Vale ya he editado mi respuesta, espero que esta vez si te sirva de ayuda ;)

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, muchísimas gracias :)